# Determine "reach" by geographic distribution

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, geolocation, geospatial

I have a large collection of checkins for products manufactured at a distinct geographic location. I'd like to create a summary metric used to rank these products by how far, globally, they have traveled from their point of origin. For example, a product produced in Maine that is found in California, Florida, and Dublin, Ireland should rank higher than a product made in California that hasn't been seen outside of California.

What kind of algorithms should I be looking at? How would you approach this?

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL Server (which I've just spotted may not be relevant to you) includes spatial data types that allow you to calculate (among other things) the distance between two points defined by their latitude and longitude.  So this code:-

```
DECLARE @p1 geography = geography::Point(@lat1, @long1, 4326);

SELECT @distance=@p1.STDistance(geography::Point(@lat2, @long2, 4326))
```

would load @distance with the distance in metres between the two points.  I lifted the code from a scalar valued in line function that I wrote - but it could also be targeting table columns directly.  The 4326 magic number is a reference to the Spatial Reference System Identifier (SRID) that provides answers in metres.  This calculation doesn't take into account altitude and the distortion of the globe (other functions/SRIDs are available for this) but it's probably accurate enough for most purposes.

Unfortunately, if you are restricted to postgresql, this answer is of no use (though it may point you in a direction for further investigation).

A reference for Sql Server can be found here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx